# Assistance with SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Right now I have two separate queries to achieve the results but I would like one query. I'm using MS Access.

```
tblJournal          tblArticle      tblStatus
----------          ----------      ---------
JournalID           ArticleID       ID
JournalTitle        JournalCode     StatusName
JournalCode         StatusID       
Cancelled(yes/no)   Date
                    ArticleTitle
                    SignedDate
```

The query should have:

```
tblJournal.JournalTitle, 
tblJournal.JournalCode, 
Year([tblArticle].[Date]), 
Count of articles per year which have a tblArticle.SignedDate, 
Count of articles per year with tblStatus.StatusName 'Published' and tblJournal.Cancelled NO.
```

Comment: What does ID in Table status represent? Journal ID or Article ID?

Comment: @bonsvr tblArticle.StatusID => tblStatus.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  tblJournal.JournalTitle, 
  tblJournal.JournalCode, 
  Year([tblArticle].[Date]),
  Count(tblArticle.SignedDate) as Tot_Articles_Year,
  Sum(IIF((not tblJournal.Cancelled) and (tblStatus.StatusName='Published'),1,0)) as Tot_Published
FROM
  (tblJournal LEFT JOIN tblArticle
   ON tblJournal.JournalCode = tblArticle.JournalCode)
  LEFT JOIN tblStatus
  ON tblArticle.StatusID = tblStatus.ID
GROUP BY 
  tblJournal.JournalTitle, 
  tblJournal.JournalCode, 
  Year([tblArticle].[Date])
```

Comment: Yes this looks like its working. Will run more tests to be sure. Never thought of using Sum, I was only looking at Count. Thanks!

Comment: @tutu let me know if you have any problem, i changed first sum with a count (if SignedDate is null, it won't be counted), but we need to use  sum for the second count